# Powershell regex to extract data from log file

Tags: regex, powershell

Working on a script to extract data from log file; terms in a search query and execution time.

sample from the log file

```
19/08/2016 09:08:00 [100] ACTION%3DQuery%26MaxResults%3D9999%26abridged%3Dtrue%26abridgedmeta%3Ddatabase%26printfields%3DIM_DOCNUM,IM_VERSION%26combine%3Dfieldcheck%26databasematch%3DDATABASE_1,DATABASE-2%26Text%3D((pep21556)%3AIM_DOCNAME)%26fieldtext%3D(WILD%7BWORK%7D%3AIM_PRJ_SUBTYPE+AND+WILD%7BWEBDOC%7D%3AIM_CLASS)+AND+BIASDATE%7B1471612079e,2592000,20%7D%3Aautn_date+AND+BIASDATE%7B1471612079e,63072000,20%7D%3Aautn_date%26anyLanguage%3Dtrue%26TimeoutMS%3D60000
19/08/2016 09:08:00 [100] Request completed in 12 ms.
19/08/2016 09:08:28 [103] Request from 10.1.1.131
```

the log file is URL encoded.

My work in progress script loads the log file

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filename))
```

then URLdecods each line and removes a long securityinfo string

```
$VarURLDecoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($line) -replace "SecurityInfo=.*"
```

Now I am struggling with the RegEx to extract the following : Date +Time, MaxResault=xxxxxxx, Text=((??????????):???????) and the time in ms for the request to complete in the following line.

```
$findText = $VarURLDecoded | select-string -Inputobject {$_} -pattern
```

I have some partial regex pieces.

```
'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'  will find 19/08/2016 09:08:00
'MaxResults=(\d*)' will find MaxResults=9999
'(?<Text>&Text=\(\([^()]*\)\:[^()]*\))' will find &Text=((campeau):IM_DOCNAME)
'(\d* ms)' will find the xx ms
```

But can't figure out the AND syntax to join them all including the duration record that is on the second line. Either use the fact it follows the line under or the fact it has a proper time stamp.

Once I get the basic regex working I can add complexity by adding named groups and exporting the results to a hash table.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the posted log there's no need to decode it as there are no `%xx`-encoded characters.
For text processing there's no need for kinda low-level stuff like `[System.IO.File]`.
An additional line is needed so let's use `-context before, after` parameter.

```
$report = select-string -path $filename -context 0,1 -pattern (
    '^(?<date>.+?) ' +
    '(?<time>.+?) .+?' +
    '&MaxResults=(?<results>\d+).+?' +
    '&Text=(?<text>[^&]+)') |
%{
    $nextLine = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
    $g = $_.matches[0].groups
    @{
        date = $g['date'].value
        time = $g['time'].value
        results = $g['results'].value
        text = $g['text'].value
        duration = if ($nextLine -match 'completed in (\d+) ms') { $matches[1] }
    }
}
```

`$report` now is an array of objects each as follows:

> ```
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> date                           19/08/2016
> time                           09:08:00
> duration                       12
> results                        9999
> text                           ((pep21556):IM_DOCNAME)
> ```

Alternatively, taking in account select-string's pattern matching may be slow with a complex pattern, let's match using a simple string, filter with `?` (alias for `Where-Object`), then process the results:

```
$report = select-string -path $filename -context 0,1 -pattern '&MaxResults=' -simpleMatch |
?{ $_.Line -match (
    '^(?<date>.+?) ' +
    '(?<time>.+?) .+?' +
    '&MaxResults=(?<results>\d+).+?' +
    '&Text=(?<text>[^&]+)')
} | %{
    $nextLine = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
    $m = $matches # $matches is set by the above -match
    @{
        date = $m['date']
        time = $m['time']
        results = $m['results']
        text = $m['text']
        duration = if ($nextLine -match 'completed in (\d+) ms') { $matches[1] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for you answering my second question. A few points, the files I am searching are each about 100 megs in size, so I thought using the [System.IO.File] would give better performance.  And the original data is URL Encoded, ( I put the decoded sample to make me question easier to explain.  I have adapted your code, to my original script but the duration field is bank.  I am wondering if this is because it does not work with the system.IO.File

Comment: Tried ::readAllText instead of ::ReadLines and result was script no longer finds anything.  So what change would be required in your solution script to deal with URLEncode lines ?  ( again each file is about 100 megs and has close to 1 million lines)

Comment: Pipe the lines: `[IO.File]::ReadAllLines($filename) | select-string .....`

Comment: Got that part but the data coming in is still URL encoded, not sure how to decode each line with your pipe example ?

Comment: `?{ [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($_.Line) -match (`

Comment: Sorry again for not understanding would the 1st line of your script now look like this ?  $report = [IO.File]::ReadAllLines($filename) | ?{ [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($_.Line) -match} | select-string  -context 0,1 -pattern '&MaxResults=' -simpleMatch ....

Comment: Er, that was for the second code snippet, instead of `?{ $_.Line -match (` To make it work in the first snippet I suppose you'd have to replace `&` with whatever the encoded character is, probably `&amp;` or `%26`. Next time show the log file excerpt as-is in the description.

Comment: Your suggested edit uses `&` in the first pattern but as I just said you should use the actual separator.

Comment: With your suggestion script is now working ! But I have found one type of entry I would like to delete from the hashtable, when  text=*  (I am using the * as a literal character) Something like foreach ($line in $report.keys) {if $line.containsValue"*" .remove }.  The valid entries in the hashtable contain text=(test here)